# How to extract and use*.osm.bz2 file for Android?

Tags: java, android, extract, openstreetmap

I have downloaded the file philippines.osm.bz2 from a site. Now I don't know what to do next with this file. I mean what are the software that I should need to use this file? My plan is to display a Map of the philippines from OSM file like philippines.osm.bz2 and display it on an Android project offline.

Are there any libraries that I can use to be able to combine .osm map files and merge it to Android. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.osm files are way too large for using them directly on a Smartphone/Tablet.

For a quick start I suggest you to use [MapDroyd](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.osa.android.mapdroyd&hl=de) which has a built in download functionality for regions world wide. The downloaded data has been derived from .osm files but they are optimized and reduced for mobile usage.

A different approach is the [MapsForge](http://code.google.com/p/mapsforge/) vector file format which is supported by some Apps like [Locus](https://market.android.com/details?id=menion.android.locus).

Unfortunately ready-to-use maps are at the moment only available for Europe:
ftp://ftp.mapsforge.org/maps/

For building your own app I would definitely take a closer look onto the MapsForge project. In includes a [renderer](http://code.google.com/p/mapsforge/wiki/MobileMapRendering) that draws a map based on the vector information stored in the .map files. AFAIR those files can be created by converting .osm/.pbf files on a regular PC.

Comment: First of all thank you for answering. MapDroyd is closed source, I am  a beginner sir, I need a clue on  creating Android Projects that will optimized the use of OpenStreetMap, without having large osm files into the project.

Comment: Again thank for answering. I have a quick overview on MapsForge project. And I have found some keypoints in understanding the project. Please correct me if i'm wrong. Map tiles, slippy map, also mentioned Osmarender. Please bare with me sir Robert, I am still a student. How do i create map tiles? How do I integrate it with slippy map? What software should I use to use them? Sir Robert, I know I am not supposed to asked many questions and i should research in the net but i spent 3 weeks overtime to research then i have not found any results. thank you sir.

Comment: Generating map tiles (bitmap tiles of size 256x256 pixel) is often very complex. Most programs just download them from openstreetmap.org. Using bitmap tiles or vector data is a general decision you have to make. Painting vector data on a mobile device needs a lot of CPU power.

Answer (score 0):

OSM files are [OpenStreetMap](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/) files. There are various Android projects that can read OSM files. This one seems to be the most developed one: http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/

Comment: I was able to check out the osmdroid project many times, in what folder could i see the osm files. Does it need an internet connection to generate its map or they stored it in locally?

Comment: AFAIR Osmdroid uses (only?) bitmap tiles - not the OSM vector data.